# JSF-generated HTML element ID is changing, how to set it to a fixed element ID?

Tags: jsf, element, identifier

I have a JSF input text component which has an id of `search`. In the generated HTML output it looks like this `j_idt17:search`, but the number `17` is changing from time to time. How to make it to stay one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give the JSF component which generated the HTML element with `id="j_idt17"` a fixed ID. In this particular case, it's likely the HTML input element's parent `<form>` element which is generated by the JSF `<h:form>` component.

So, this should do:

```
<h:form id="form">
```

This way the ID of the generated HTML `<input>` element will become `form:search`.